# Laravel 5.7 override default model table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know I can override a table in a model by doing

```
protected $table = 'my_custom_table';
```

But is there a way to enforce custom table naming convention so that I don't have to do this in each model separately?

For example:

```
public function getTable(){
    return env('DB_PREFIX') . '_' . $module_name . '_' . $entity_name
}
```

Comment: Inside the configuration folder you find database.php, in every drive you could define an prefix this prefix will be added to every table. Is this what you want, or do you want a whole custom table name "structure" ?

Comment: Yes you can. How do you define `$module_name` & `$entity_name` ?

Comment: I'm not sure of Laravel supports this by default. You could make a custom model class that inherit `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, override the getTable method and you can implement custom logics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Romano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4897013/romano-schoonheim) sugested, I made a custom model which would extend the Eloquent one, and every subsequent model I made would extend mine instead of Eloquent one.

```
namespace App;

use App\Traits\FindCaller;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GenericModel extends Model
{
    use FindCaller;

    const CREATED_AT = 'creation_time';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'last_modified_time';
    const DELETED_AT = 'deleted_time';

    /**
     * Override to make the default model table name = "module_model"
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTable()
    {
        if(!$this->table) {
            list($module, $model) = $this->getModelCallerEntities();
            return strtolower($module . '_' . $model);
        }

        return $this->table;
    }
}
```

Each subsequent model:

```
use App\GenericModel;

class Xyz extends GenericModel
{
    ...
}
```